# count subscribers who have subscribed to all magazines(3 different magazines)

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SUBSCRIPTIONS (SUB_ID, MAG_ID, RENEW_DATE, CANCEL_DATE, PERIOD)
```

This is what I tried but all i get is a count of 0

```
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT SUB_ID)
FROM DVD_SUBSCRIPTIONS
WHERE MAG_ID = 1
AND MAG_ID = 2
AND MAG_ID = 3;


COUNT(DISTINCTSUB_ID)
 ---------------------
              0
```

Help plzzz

Comment: Can you provide the sample input data with expected output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The following should work, the inner SELECT will return the subsribers that have subsribed to all 3 magazines:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
  FROM (SELECT sub_id, COUNT(distinct mag_id) 
          FROM dvd_subscriptions 
         WHERE mag_id IN (1, 2, 3) 
         GROUP BY sub_id
        HAVING COUNT(distinct mag_id) = 3)
```

Comment: +1 although I would have reduced the inner SELECT clause to some simple literal.

Comment: I've never seen an inner select.  Didn't know it was possible to put a select statement in a FROM.  I'm going to need to read into this more.  This was very helpful.  Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Dave you can't use `AND` like that, can you think about a value which is equal to 1 and at the same time 2 and 3? You should use `IN` clause or you can use `OR` but this one get you the data where `mag_id = 1` or `mag_id = 2` or `mag_id = 3`.If you want all of them use `IN` clause like the one in Vincent's answer.

check these links to learn more : [SQL-AND-OR](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-AND-OR.asp), [SQL-IN](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-IN.asp), [SQL-HAVING](http://www.sql-tutorial.net/SQL-HAVING.asp)